# How to import Jquery in Background service worker - Manifest V3 - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
```

I need to use Jquery in background.js. I cannot add jquery.min.js in the manifest because with the new upgrade v3 I cannot declare more than one JS in service_worker. How can I solve?

background.js

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "https://wwww",
   data: {text: "xxx"}
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**jQuery is DOM-based so its $.ajax or $.put or $.get won't run in the service worker** as there's no DOM/document/window, consequently no XMLHttpRequest, which is used by these methods. The other DOM-based features of jQuery are also unusable in a service worker.

**Solution #1 is to use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)**.
There are also fetch-based libraries if you need more bells and whistles like onprogress.

**Solution #2 is to use `jQuery.ajax` inside an [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) document in Chrome 109+.**

Comment: I have added "importScripts('js/jquery.js')" but it get error "Service worker registration failed"

Comment: It means the path is incorrect, see the more info link in the answer for workarounds.

Comment: Another possibility is that jquery.js failed because workers don't have DOM. Like I said, don't use jquery.\

Comment: @wOxxOm: in what way is `$.get()` or `$.put()` DOM-based? I used jquery AJAX statements in background.js under manifest v 2 without problem.

Comment: @danbae many things got f`up in v3:( I can't use it either. did you find the workaround?

Comment: @Volatil3 I used `fetch()` just as the man said :) It works fine.

Comment: @danbae I did same but it is being called once when I refresh the extension, not everytime the page is loaded

Comment: @Volatil3 if your `fetch()` command is in the background service worker, it needs to be called from somewhere. If it is to be called every time the page is loaded, the `content.js` can send a message – triggered by `$(document).ready()` – to the service worker to activate the `fetch()`. In my demo extension doing just that, the `fetch()` command in the service worker gets activated upon every page load and reload.

Comment: but in manifest v2 jquerry could be loaded in bg scripts too but in v3 its giving windows not defined and all that dom error

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a [JQuery-noDOM](https://github.com/kpozin/jquery-nodom) to use ajax etc without retyping your code using fetch.